# How to solve exercises with polynomial with 2 parameters having all real roots?

Tags: polynomials

$f=2x^{4}+4x^{3}+3x^{2}+bx+c$ has all real roots, find b,c (b,c are from R).
Thanks a lot, I tried with substitution, I don't know, is there something with derivative? please help thanks

Comment: Well, between any two zeros of the function, there's a zero of the derivative, though I'm not sure this helps.

Comment: Is the exercise to find **every** pair $b,c$ for which $f$ has only real roots, or is it to find just one such pair? Also, please give us some context. Where did you come across this problem? What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @saulspatz In this case it certainly helps, since that observation implies a condition on the discriminant of $f'$ and hence a condition on $b$ alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g(x)=2x^4+4x^3+3x^2$.  Then $g''(z)=24x^2+24x+6=6(2x+1)^2\geq0$.  So $g$ is convex, and will intersect a line at most twice.  In order for $f(x)$ to have only real roots, the line $y=-bx-c$ will have to be tangent to the graph of $g$.  But the tangent will not intersect the graph in a second point, so if $f$ has $4$ real zeros, it must have a quadruple zero, that is $f$ and its first three derivatives must vanish at some point.

The computation above shows that this point must be $x=-\frac12$ and we must have $$f(x)=2\left(x+\frac12\right)^4.$$

I haven't carried it past this point.  I leave it to you.

Comment: oh ok, didn't know about that, thanks a lot, I got it

Answer (score 3):

$f$ has $4$ (not necessarily distinct) real roots, say $r, s, t, u$. Hence, $f$ can be factorized this way : $f = 2 (x-r) (x -s) (x-t) (x - u)$. If you developp this expression, and compare term by term, you'll get that the roots satisfy he following system of equations (**edited** 4 equations, as pointed out by @saulspatz) :
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{ccl} 
c & =  & 2 rstu \\
b & = & -2(rst + rsu + rtu + stu) \\
3 & = & 2 (rs + rt + ru + st + su + tu) \\
4 & = & -2(r + s + t + u) \end{array}\right. $$

Granted, this looks ugly, but only the last two lines represents a constraint. e.g. take $r = s = t = u = \frac{-1}{2}$, this satisfies the two last lines and hence you get a solution where $b = 1$ and $c = \frac{1}{8}$.

Comment: This should be a system of 4 equations: The third equation should have $3$ on the left-hand side (since it corresponds to the quadratic term), and the cubic term gives us the last of Vieta's formulas: $4 = -2(r + s + t + u)$

Comment: When I [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2x%5E4%2B4x%5E3%2B3x%5E2-%288sqrt%283%29%2F9%29x%2B2%2F9) it, it doesn't seem to have any real roots.

Comment: yes, something is not right, I don't know if you can make it with viete, sorry for that

Comment: @TravisWillse is it possible with viete?

Comment: Possibly. That's what Olivier's answer does, except for the transcription error I mentioned above. saulsplatz' answer is possibly the best elementary answer. Another option is to use saulsplatz' comment under the original question, which shows that $f'$ must have three real roots. In terms of the variable $x = y - \frac{1}{2}$, the derivative is $f' = 8y^3 + (b - 1)$. But (for any $b$) this function is nondecreasing, so it has three real roots iff all of those roots coincide, i.e., if $b - 1 = 0$. Substituting in the original equation gives $f = 2 y^4 + \left(c - \frac{1}{8}\right)$.

Comment: @TravisWillse Oh ok, thanks a lot for the comment

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = 2x^4+4x^3+3x^2+bx+c$

If $f(x)$ has all $4$ roots to be real and complex, then it's discriminate $$\Delta = (-72)b^2+176b^3-108b^4-864c-2304bc+1536b^2c+2304c^2-3072bc^2+2048c^3$$ must be real, $\Delta > 0$
Also if you divide $f(x)$ by 2, and make a translation $x = y-\frac{1}{2}$

$2x^4+4x^3+3x^2+bx+c = 0$

$x^4+2x^3+\frac{3/2}x^2+\frac{b/2}x+\frac{c/2} = 0$

Say $x = y-\frac{1}{2}$

The equation is depressed that suddenly appear to be

$y^4+(\frac{b}{2}-\frac{1}{2})y+\frac{c}{2}-\frac{b}{4}+\frac{3}{16} = 0$

Notice that the $y^2$ automatically vanishes

Defined $D = 512c-256b+192$

For the polynomial to therefore have real distinct root $D < 0$ and $\Delta > 0$

[Nature of roots](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function)

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of calculus to do, thanks